# Error while adding new row to the database

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am trying to save the data to database on save button click event but getting error in respository code as shown below. Please help me resolving this.

Here is my list.cshtml code:

```
    var saveTrainingProgram = function () {
    console.log('in save');

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Affiliate/TrainingProgram/Save',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            trainingProgramName: ff.trainingProgramName.val(),
            colorCode: ff.colorCode.val()
        }
    }).done(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 'success') {

            var html = buildEntryHtml(entry, (trainingProgramId == 0));
        } else {

        }
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {

        $.isLoading('hide');
    });

    clearForm();
};

var clearForm = function () {
    el.addForm.find('.form-control input').val();
    el.addForm.find('select training-program-name').prop('selected', true).trigger('change');
    // clear if Validation errors exist.
    trainingProgramValidator.resetForm();
};
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "Affiliate")]
public ActionResult Save(string trainingProgramName, stringcolorCode)
{
    CbJsonResponse response = new CbJsonResponse();
    int errorCount = 0;
    List<string> errorMessages = new List<string>(5);


    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(trainingProgramName))
    {
        errorCount++;
        errorMessages.Add("Error: The Training Program Name is required.");
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(colorCode))
    {
        colorCode = CbConstants.TrainingProgramDefaultColorCode;
    }

    if (errorCount == 0)
    {
        Entities.TrainingProgram trainingProgram = new Entities.TrainingProgram();
        trainingProgram.Name = trainingProgramName;
        trainingProgram.ColorCode = colorCode;

        if (TrainingProgramRepository.Instance.SaveTrainingProgram(trainingProgram))
        {
            response.Status = "success";
            TrainingProgramListEntry listEntry = new TrainingProgramListEntry()
            {
                ID = trainingProgram.ID,
                Name = trainingProgram.Name,
                ColorCode = trainingProgram.ColorCode
            };

            // Include the list entry in the response.
            response.Data.Add(listEntry);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        response.Status = "failure";
        response.Meta.Add("errorCount", Convert.ToString(errorCount));
        response.Data.Add(errorMessages);
    }

    return Json(response, "application/json", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Repository :

```
public bool SaveTrainingProgram(TrainingProgram trainingProgram)
{
    bool retVal = false;
    using (var ctx = new CrossfitPortalEntities())
    {

        try
        {
            ctx.TrainingPrograms.Add(trainingProgram);
            retVal = (ctx.SaveChanges() > 0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Debug("Unable to save training program.", ex);
        }
    }
    return retVal; // retVal should be true but it is false
}
```

Comment: Try to replace `Exception ex` with `DbUpdateException ex`. Then, checking for `ex.Message` for more detail.

Comment: what's the exception?

Comment: On Save click we are passing the trainingprogram viewmodel in that by default id is setting as 0 . so getting error as cant pass the values to identity column which is set off

Comment: id is the pk, but it is showing 0 instead of null

Comment: "default id is setting as 0". Maybe change the default to be null then? And please clarify the definition of your ID column in the database - maybe give us an extract from the CREATE script for this table.

Comment: Are you using entity framework  or any ORM?

Comment: i am using entity framework 6

Comment: but i should not change the entities. is there any other way to resolve this issue.

Comment: I repeat please show us the definition of your ID field.

Comment: it is auto generated   public int ID { get; set; }

Comment: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'TrainingPrograms' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. this is the error

Comment: no i mean the definition in the _database_ (i.e. script the table as a create and get the definition of the field). Does it specify a default value or an autoincrement?

Comment: The database table has an identity column, but the property is not mapped as `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`.